# Why is 'fig build' returning: AttributeError: 'WrappedSocket' object has no attribute 'recvfrom'?

Tags: python, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, fig

My command: (I tried fig build --no-cache as well)

```
fig build
db uses an image, skipping
Building web...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/fig", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('fig==1.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'fig')()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/main.py", line 31, in main
command.sys_dispatch()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/docopt_command.py", line 21, in sys_dispatch
self.dispatch(sys.argv[1:], None)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/command.py", line 28, in dispatch
super(Command, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/docopt_command.py", line 24, in dispatch
self.perform_command(*self.parse(argv, global_options))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/command.py", line 56, in perform_command
handler(project, command_options)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/main.py", line 119, in build
project.build(service_names=options['SERVICE'], no_cache=no_cache)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/project.py", line 166, in build
service.build(no_cache)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/service.py", line 397, in build
all_events = stream_output(build_output, sys.stdout)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/progress_stream.py", line 17, in stream_output
for chunk in output:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 279, in _stream_helper
socket_fp = socket_obj(_sock=self._get_raw_response_socket(response))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 190, in __init__
setattr(self, method, getattr(_sock, method))
AttributeError: 'WrappedSocket' object has no attribute 'recvfrom'
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
```

Fig.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  links:
   - db
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  volumes:
   - Symfony/:/var/www/html/
  environment:
   SYMFONY_ENV: dev
db:
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

I've tried fig build with an empty fig.yml and I still get the error, I think it might have something to do with some SSL errors I was getting so I installed

```
pip install requests[security]
```

I tried uninstalling requests and fig and reinstalling them both.

This is all MacOSX Yosemite using boot2docker (it's running).

```
boot2docker -v
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.6.2
Git commit: cb2c3bc

docker version
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64

fig --version
fig 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the security package I installed with pip required a newer version of Python. I pretty much followed this guide step by step to upgrade Python and everything worked like a charm: https://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/

Answer (score 1):

As displayed on [fig's web site](http://www.fig.sh):

> Fig has been replaced by Docker Compose, and is now deprecated. The new documentation is on the [Docker website](http://docs.docker.com/compose/).

You should use Docker Compose.